# Using external java-scripts inside reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am using an external js file inside a helmet tag within my reactjs application

```
import {Helmet} from "react-helmet";
...
<Helmet>
                <meta charSet="utf-8" />
                <title>My Title</title>
                <link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/example" />
                <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue" type="text/javascript" />
                  <script src="assets/my-app.js" type="text/javascript" />
            </Helmet>
```

But the problem that I see in chrome logs, it can not read the js file correctly and gives me

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < on
```

I am not sure where to put the java script external file inside my react app so it is regarded as the java script external file?

EDIT:
Based on response below, I am using now localhost:3000/my-app.js, but is there any variable to use instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it inside of the index.html file in the public folder.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your response, I am using now http://localhost:3000/my-app.js, but is there any variable to use instead?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the path to your script file is correct. If your JS file is in assets folder, use the proper relative or absolute path to the JS file

If you use "assets/my-app.js", then it will look for the assets folder in current directory

Comment: As I told, this answer is incorrect and makes error for my use-case since it renders it as html not a pure js text file!

Comment: I checked react-helmet npm package. It supports <script> tags. Maybe you are trying to use it without knowing the purpose